# Why is peewee not nesting this WHERE clause correctly?

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I'm creating a query like this in the Python [peewee ORM](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/):

```
myTableModel.records = myTableModel.select(
    myTableModel.table_field_name
    ).where(
    (myTableModel.second_field_name.is_null(True) |
    myTableModel.second_field_name == "")
    )
```

I can work back to the SQL generated by running `print myTableModel.records.sql()`

```
SELECT `t1`.`table_field_name`
FROM `table_name` AS t1
WHERE (((`t1`.`second_field_name` IS NULL) OR `t1`.`second_field_name`) = '');
```

This is not using the correct nesting. This is the statement I want:

```
SELECT `t1`.`table_field_name`
FROM `table_name` AS t1
WHERE `t1`.`second_field_name` IS NULL OR `t1`.`second_field_name` = '';
```

The existing `WHERE` clause boils down to this ...

```
WHERE `t1`.`second_field_name` IS NULL = ''
```

... which produces exactly the opposite of what I want, returning all rows where `second_field_name` is **not** `NULL`.

How do I fix this? Did I nest the Python code incorrectly somehow?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Through trial and error, I've found that adding two more parentheses fixes the query. Parentheses must be added around `myTableModel.second_field_name == ""` like so:

```
myTableModel.records = myTableModel.select(
    myTableModel.table_field_name
    ).where(
    (myTableModel.second_field_name.is_null(True) |
    (myTableModel.second_field_name == ""))
    )
```

I'm not sure exactly why this helps. It seems like Python and peewee ought to be able to use the pipe and outer parentheses as delimiters.

Comment: I've created an issue for this on the peewee github https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/issues/769

Answer (score 1):

Peewee leans on Python's parser to generate expressions. Because of Python's [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) you need parentheses around most comparisons. No magic here, just Python.

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html?highlight=precedence#expressions

Comment: Can you define "most"? This seems maddeningly inconsistent. For example, this works `.where(modelObject.field_name << ['a','b','c'] | modelObject.field_name % '%word%')`

Comment: Just put parentheses around all binary expressions, then you won't have issues. It won't affect the query at all, and you'll be sure you're getting the right results. In the docs and pretty much everywhere, every single snippet of code does this. Also see http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html?highlight=precedence#expressions